# How can I add some spacing between fields with Laravel filament?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I'm just learning Laravel filament and I'm enjoying the experience so far. I managed to build a settings page with some fields with the help of the documentation. But now I want to add some spacing between these fields. I was thinking of inserting a div with some tailwind classes.

What do you think guys is it possible or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Should be able to use `extraAttributes` on a field or layout element to apply Tailwind classes to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using extraAttributes to add tailwind css. But for me, I would rather do that in a nested grid instead, much easier and for page responsiveness.